# Flutter/Dart - Unable to refresh the value of static variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this:

```
class PageService {
  static int CurrentPage = 0;
}
```

And I have this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../services/page_service.dart';

class NavigationMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationMenu({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavigationMenu> createState() => _NavigationMenuState();
}

class _NavigationMenuState extends State<NavigationMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationBar(
      destinations: const [
        NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: "Home"),
        NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.forum), label: "Forums"),
      ],
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 154, 15, 5),
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          PageService.CurrentPage = index;
          int test = PageService.CurrentPage;
          print("SETTING $test");
        });
      },
      selectedIndex: PageService.CurrentPage,
    );
  }
}
```

Then in my main, I have this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'BeastBurst',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const BeastBurst(title: 'BeastBurst'),
    );
  }
}

class BeastBurst extends StatefulWidget {
  const BeastBurst({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<BeastBurst> createState() => _BeastBurstState();
}

class _BeastBurstState extends State<BeastBurst> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool _loggedIn = false;

  List<Widget> pages = const [HomePage(), Forums()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages[PageService.CurrentPage],
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

When I navigate over the navigation menu I see the output of print like:

```
SETTING 1
SETTING 0
SETTING 1
SETTING 1
```

However, page switching does not happen unless I press `CRTL+S` on the VSCode editor.
Looks like it reads the value of `PageService.CurrentPage` only on the editor save.

This issue happened once I made `PageService.CurrentPage` static. Any idea why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you include more about `main` widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here, in your `NavigationMenu` class you're updating the state of the class and not it's parent class, in which you're using the `NavigationMenu`, which is why the state of the parent class isn't' changed and the build method isn't recalled and the updated value of `PageService.CurrentIndex` isn't referenced again.

**In the class where you have used the `NavigationMenu`:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationMenu(
        onDestinationSelected: (index) {
          setState(() {
            PageService.CurrentPage = index;
            int test = PageService.CurrentPage;
            print("SETTING $test");
          });
        },
      ),
      body: pages[PageService.CurrentPage],
    );
  }
```

**Updated `NavigationMenu` class:**

```
class NavigationMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) onDestinationSelected;
  const NavigationMenu({super.key, required this.onDestinationSelected});

  @override
  State<NavigationMenu> createState() => _NavigationMenuState();
}

class _NavigationMenuState extends State<NavigationMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationBar(
      destinations: const [
        NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: "Home"),
        NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.forum), label: "Forums"),
      ],
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 154, 15, 5),
      onDestinationSelected: widget.onDestinationSelected,
      selectedIndex: PageService.CurrentPage,
    );
  }
}
```

**Alternate solution:**

**In your `NavigationMenu` class, change:**

```
onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      PageService.CurrentPage = index;
      int test = PageService.CurrentPage;
      print("SETTING $test");
    });
  }
```

**to:**

```
onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
  final parentState = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyHomePageState>();
  
  parentState?.setState(() {
    PageService.CurrentPage = index;
    int test = PageService.CurrentPage;
    print("SETTING $test");
  });
}
```

Note: Change `_MyHomePageState` to your class state in which you're using the `NavigationMenu`.

Comment: Hey `NavigationMenu ` is used over several classes, not just one.

Comment: @Venelin, I have updated my answer, used callback function to setstate in the class where the NavigationMenu is used.

Comment: Tried both ways none work. See the updated question I've added info there about the main class.

Comment: Worked I had t reload fully.

Comment: @Venelin, I don't see that you followed my answer. You have set the callback in the NavigationMenu class  but I did something else .Check the answer.

Comment: Cool then, I thought how it couldn't work when I just tested :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make main widget as `StatefulWidget` while will update the UI here too. I am using a callback method instead of global variable.

```dart
class NavigationMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationMenu({super.key, required this.selected});

  final Function(int) selected;
```

```
//....
      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
        widget.selected(index);//update parent callback
        setState(() {});
      },
      selectedIndex: PageService.CurrentPage,
    );
  }
```

And use case

```
class _ExampleScreenState extends State<ExampleScreen> {
  int activeIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationMenu(
          selected: (p0) {
            //PageService.CurrentPage=0;
              activeIndex = p0;
             setState(() {});
          },
        ),
        body: [Text("a"), Text("B")][activeIndex] //PageService.CurrentPage
```

Comment: Hello I've added more to the question.

Comment: Does my snippet fail?

Comment: The snippet is really broad and it seems not addressing the static variable issue I am experiencing :(

Comment: yap, global variable isnt needed here. just track the `final Function(int) selected;` you will get it